# Removing master page when submitting ajax form submit

Tags: jquery

I write a form with jquery ajax form in asp.net (c#) .When I submitting a form with ajax submit ,the master page and form show again.I want to move master page.How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

first you should include how you do the submit the form.

Most likely is that you do sending your data with one button, and this also made the submit the form.

One way is to cancel the submit the form with jQuery, and sending the data via ajax.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {return false;}); 

$("#miButton").submit(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   //code for send data with ajax
   //...
});
```